# Spring Boot parses JSON wrong: instead of collection of dto class to collection of LinkedHashMap in @RequestBody

Tags: json, spring-boot, jackson, collection-json

In my Spring Boot controller I have an endpoint that accepts HashMap<String, Collection> as POST body.
The method is declared like this:

```
@PutMapping()
public ResponseEntity<ConfirmDto> save(@RequestBody HashMap<String, @Valid Collection<DataDto>> dataDtos) {
...
}
```

JSON data is something like:

```
{
"toDelete": [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "XY"
  }
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "XYZ"
  }
],
"toSave": [
  {
    "id": null,
    "name": "HQL"
  }
]
}
```

DataDto is not passed correctly and has type LinkedHashMap. I suspect that Jackson fails to parse the JSON input. The Dto class has all getters and setters, also empty constructor. The JSON data sent is corresponding to the Dto class. This code used to work with Spring Boot 2.x and Spring Boot 3.0.8 then I updated to 3.2.0 and it fails.

Now I use Spring Boot 3.2.0 and have all dependencies managed by gradle plugin.
Dependencies are:

```
implementation(
            "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa",
            "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web",
            "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation",
            "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security",
            "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator",

            "org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-core:$springOauthVersion",
            "org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-resource-server:$springOauthVersion",
            "org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose:$springOauthVersion",

            "org.flywaydb:flyway-core",
            "org.flywaydb:flyway-mysql",
            "com.h2database:h2",
            "org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.11",
            "org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:4.4",
            "commons-io:commons-io:2.8.0",
            "io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.1",
            "io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0",
            'org.json:json:20230227',
            "org.javers:javers-spring-boot-starter-sql:7.3.6",
    )
```

I tried using my application as I used to after the upgrade but it threw ClassCastException: class java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to class ...

I don't really understand why it is happening and run out of ideas how to fix it since usually the framework handles JSON parsing. I appreciate your help and explanation.